# Which latest cuda toolkit and tensorflow versions are compatible?

Tags: tensorflow

As given on this site https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu, I feel like it haven't been updated in a while so can someone tell me if tensorflow version 2.10. is compatible with cuda toolkit versions higher than 11.2 as 11.2 is only for windows 10 and not 11.

Answer (score 1):

I am using CUDA 11.8.0 and CUDNN 8.9.7.29. Please make sure you follow the tutorial [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#prerequisites-windows).

It runs with TensorFlow 2.10.0. Proof the GPU can detected [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLu7t.png).

Answer (score 0):

These are updated and tested [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) details.

TensorFlow 2.10 is compatible with CUDA 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1 for GPU support on **Windows 7 (64 bit) or later (with C++ redistributable)**. You can find these details in [System Requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system_requirements) section of TensorFlow install page.

TensorFlow > 2.10 is not compatible for GPU support in Windows native. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you need to install TensorFlow in WSL2 for GPU setup which requires **Windows 10 19044 or higher (64-bit)**.

Answer (score 0):

I tried about them. I think cuda version is not related. For using gpu, I installed tensorflow2.10.0-gpu. The python version is 3.10.9 because tensorflow 2.10.0 is accessible in lower verion than python 3.11.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).